# Большая или маленькая буква? "Второй пермский конгресс ученых-юристов"?

Tags: грамматика

Нужно ли писать второе слово в сочетании с большой буквы: "Второй пермский конгресс ученых-юристов"?

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: "Второй пермский конгресс ученых-юристов".

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Имена прилагательные с суффиксом СК являются относительно-притяжательными прилагательными.  В большинстве случаев  они не  обозначают индивидуальную принадлежность и поэтому пишутся со строчной буквы:  шекспировские трагедии, пушкинский стиль, рентгеновские лучи.

Относительно-притяжательные прилагательные с суффиксом СК пишутся с прописной буквы, если являются ПЕРВЫМ СЛОВОМ составного имени собственного: Булгаковские вечера, Пушкинские чтения, Толстовский музей. Однако в нашем случае это второе слово.

Answer (score 0):

**Нет**. Пишутся с прописной буквы прилагательные, образованные от собственных географических названий:

а) если они входят в состав сложных географических названий, например: Бельгийское Конго, Московская область;

б) если они входят в состав сложных индивидуальных названий людей в качестве их прозвищ, например: Димитрий Донской, Александр Невский, Петр Амьенский;

в) если они входят в состав сложных названий исторических событий, учреждений и т. п.

Вряд ли этот конгресс — историческое событие.